# python unit test with mock for checking file path

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have following python function in `'au.py'` :

```
import os

def resolv_conf_audit():
    ALT_PATH = "/etc/monitor/etc/resolv.conf.{}".format(os.uname()[1])
    RES_PATH = "/data/bin/resolvconf"
    if os.path.isfile(RES_PATH):

        return "PASSED", "/data/bin/resolvconf is present"

    elif os.path.isfile(ALT_PATH):
        return "PASSED", "/etc/monitor/etc/resolv.conf. is present"

    else:
        return "FAILED"
```

I need to write a unit test with mock which can check the path exists or not 
following is the unit test which I wrote

```
from au import resolv_conf_audit
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestResolvConf(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('os.path.isfile.ALT_PATH')
    def test_both_source_files_not(self, mock_os_is_file):
        mock_os_is_file.return_value =  False
        assert resolv_conf_audit() == "FAILED"
```

but I am getting following error

```
AttributeError: <function isfile at 0x10bdea6a8> does not have the attribute 'ALT_PATH'
```

How do I mock to check the presence of `ALT_PATH` and `RES_PATH` so that I can validate the function. In future this unit test should have the capability to mock removal some files, before writing that I am testing this simple one

Answer (score 1):

[Mocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) by definition is a way to simulate beahvior of objects. You are trying to handle a variable (`ALT_PATH`) inside your function.

All you need is to mock just the [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) method.

```
class TestResolvConf(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('os.path.isfile')
    def test_both_source_files_not(self, mock_os_is_file):
        mock_os_is_file.return_value =  False
        assert resolv_conf_audit() == "FAILED"

    @patch('os.path.isfile')
    def test_both_source_files_exists(self, mock_os_is_file):
        mock_os_is_file.return_value =  True
        assert resolv_conf_audit() == "PASSED"
```

Comment: Newbie question, Where does mock_os_is_file come from or gets created?  Is it a default thing created by @patch('os.path.isfile')?

Comment: This is the name you can give to mock object. I could be banana, but it may not make sense for the context :-P

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ Mauro Baraldi, as per your suggestion, I changed the code little bit and it works fine now

```
    def test_both_source_files_not(self, mock_os_is_file):
        mock_os_is_file.side_effect = [False , False]
        assert resolv_conf_audit() == "FAILED"
```